# DFS Soln to Word Search Problem in Leetcode

Tags: algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

Problem link:
https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search/

I have no idea why but the soln below is failing a **few** test cases. Please help!

My idea was to keep searching the next letter of the word to find in left, right, top and bottom elements until I found all letters. I used DFS to implement the idea.

My solution:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int vis[201][201];
    int c=0;
    void dfs(vector<vector<char>>& board, int i, int j, int m, int n, string &word, int k)
    {
        if(k==word.size())
        {
            c=1;
            return;
        }
        if(i!=m-1&&board[i+1][j]==word[k]&&vis[i+1][j]==0)
        {
            vis[i+1][j]=1;
            dfs(board,i+1,j,m,n,word,k+1);

        }
        if(j!=n-1&&board[i][j+1]==word[k]&&vis[i][j+1]==0)
        {   
          vis[i][j+1]=1;
          dfs(board,i,j+1,m,n,word,k+1);
        }
        if(i!=0&&board[i-1][j]==word[k]&&vis[i-1][j]==0)
        {   
            vis[i-1][j]=1;
            dfs(board,i-1,j,m,n,word,k+1);
        }

        if(j!=0&&board[i][j-1]==word[k]&&vis[i][j-1]==0)
        {
            vis[i][j-1]=1;
            dfs(board,i,j-1,m,n,word,k+1);
        }


    }

    bool exist(vector<vector<char>>& board, string word) 
    {
            int m=board.size();
            if(m==0)
                return false;
            int n=board[0].size();
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                    vis[i][j]=0;
            for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
                {
                    if(board[i][j]==word[0]&&vis[i][j]==0)
                    {
                        vis[i][j]=1;
                        dfs(board,i,j,m,n,word,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        if(c==1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In function bool exist(...), I guess you have to reset vis 2d array every iteration.

Because previous dfs search but had no luck, that visit can affect next search.

And also some improvement proposal, you can add c==1 condition in

if(board[i][j]==word[0]&&vis[i][j]==0)

or outer scope

because we only care about whether the word are found or not.

We have to avoid calling recursive function because it is highly cost

==================

I read code again and find out that the dfs function is not dfs, and acts more like bfs. I guess the fundamental problem from there.

And also there is time limit problem in visiting 4 direction.

1. correcting dfs

In fuction dfs, your original code like

```cpp
    void dfs(vector<vector<char>>& board, int i, int j, int m, int n, string &word, int k)
    {
        if(k==word.size())
        {
            c=1;
            return;
        }
        if(i!=m-1&&board[i+1][j]==word[k]&&vis[i+1][j]==0)
        {
            vis[i+1][j]=1;
            dfs(board,i+1,j,m,n,word,k+1);
        }

        if(j!=n-1&&board[i][j+1]==word[k]&&vis[i][j+1]==0)
        {   
          vis[i][j+1]=1;
          dfs(board,i,j+1,m,n,word,k+1);
        }
        ......
```

Lets assume that we have char map like

\ 0 1 2

0 x a b

1 c b b

and we have to find "abbbc"

as you can see, we can find "abbbc" by visiting

(0, 1) -> (0, 2) -> (1, 2) -> (1, 1) -> (1, 0) [assuming top left index is (0, 0)]

but following your code, you first visit down, so (1, 1) had marked as visit so you cannot find "abbbc"

to fix this, you have reset visited mark when finish recursion.

```cpp
        if(i!=m-1&&board[i+1][j]==word[k]&&vis[i+1][j]==0)
        {
            vis[i+1][j]=1;
            dfs(board,i+1,j,m,n,word,k+1);
            vis[i+1][j]=0; // this should add to every direction.
        }
```

also, as i mentioned at first, in exist function, you should reset visit map when calling dfs

2. time limit.

There is no way to stop dfs when the variable c already become 1.

For example, you are in good luck and found word by visiting DOWN -> DOWN -> DOWN -> DOWN.

But according to your code, the program have to visit the next possible path RIGHT -> ~~~ , UP -> ~~~, LEFT -> ~~~.

to avoid this, you have to insert return expression between calling recursion.

```cpp
        if(i!=m-1&&board[i+1][j]==word[k]&&vis[i+1][j]==0)
        {
            ~~~
        }

        if (c == 1) return;

        if(j!=n-1&&board[i][j+1]==word[k]&&vis[i][j+1]==0)
        {   
            ~~~
        }
```

This reduce much time not calling unnecessary recursion.

Comment: thanks a lot!Can you elaboarote on the time optimization point.i did it but 1 test case is failing for time limit exceed.

Comment: oh, i fixed answer. check it